# About authentification, access rules and multi views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my ASP.Net MVC3 project, I have 3 roles; manager, admin, superadmin - although there may be more in the future. There is also different views with tables and fields (manager can see 5 fields of the table, admin 7, where 2 of them have buttons like accept and decline (for trading items in an internet store), and superadmin can see all of the fields + more control buttons, like edit row, delete e.t.c.).

Now, I have 3 views for them all and 3 Controllers, this does not make best use of the DRY principle. I'd like to ask you, is it better to make 1 view for all the roles and use access rules for fields in the table, adding cell rows, history and the other views?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would favor one View with logic to determine the content shown to each role. This is more maintainable and also more testable as it will be easier to write a test to check the output for each role.

It is less of a clear issue where the logic should be put to condition the content for each role. I would keep this away from the Model and place it in the controller or a method in the ViewModel.